# Crash reporting and C++ Coroutines?

Tags: c++20, stack-trace, coroutine, crash-reports

I use a crash reporting feature that allows the user to submit a crash report if the application crashed with an uncaught exception.

After adopting C++20 coroutines entered the application.
If there is an unexpected exception thrown in a coroutine the exception is caught before it is rethrown.
This causes crashreports to not show the stacktrace needed to figure out what happened, but only the stacktrace to the coroutine that rethrew the exception. This basically makes any crash reporting useless.

As far as I could find there is no way to prevent the catching of any exceptions by the coroutine because it is a required part of the design.

Is there a way to improve this I cant see?
I am curious because I found nobody else complaining yet. :->

Edit: To clarify the app is running on Windows, I mean the stacktrace of a minidump that is created at the point of the unhandled exception using: [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setunhandledexceptionfilter) + [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump)

Comment: "*This causes crashreports to not show the stacktrace needed to figure out what happened*" - how come, before the coroutines, you have been able to receive the full stacktrace? To my knowledge, C++ does not have any utilities to do so. Have you been using C++20's `std::source_location`?

Comment: Sorry, my question may have been incomplete. The app is running on Windows and a  minidump([MiniDumpWriteDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump)) is created using [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setunhandledexceptionfilter).
I meant the stacktrace of the dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution we have found is as follows (Windows specific!):

Until now we used [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setunhandledexceptionfilter) at the start of the app to set an exceptionfilter function that writes a minidump.

Instead we now use [_set_se_translator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-se-translator?view=msvc-170).

If we want the program to just crash (f.e. if windows is set to write dumps) we set a function which calls `std::abort`.

If we want to handle it interactively we set a function which asks the user whether to send a minidump, the dump is written as before at this point.

Both cases provide the full callstack in the dump.

The only downside remaining is we cant let the program crash for "normal" exceptions to dump, this was possible before. But the "most important" exceptions (f.e. access violations) work.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have standard stack tracing yet, so there is no nice builtin way to do this.
However, there are ways, which rely on keeping information in the promise objects.
[Clang has documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DebuggingCoroutines.html) for some common debugging methods for coroutines.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear and failed to mention it is about Windows(msvc)/Minidumps post mortem debugging. As I understand it the information in the doc applies mostly only to clang/gdb.

Comment: Although this is clang documentation, you can use the same code and adapt the debugger commands to vs.

Comment: Specifically, this example’s c++ code is best for your case https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DebuggingCoroutines.html#examples-to-print-asynchronous-stack

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand how to adapt this for VS now. I will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Sadly I could not get this to work with minidumps. I think there is too much missing from the dump. (The dumps do not contain all of the heap) But my colleague had an idea that gives us the most important functionality back, I will post the workaround soon.